# SQLite is not saving my id in an android application

Tags: android, sqlite

Simple problem which got me stuck for hours now...

When I add a value into my database via db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, myValues) the new id of my item is returned.

Exactly after this call I'd like to update my entry. Therefore I call `db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, MY_ID_NAME + " = " + returnedId, null)`. I'd expect to get 1 returned as one entry is affected by this update.

However, I get 0. My id is simply not saved into the database. If I try more complex queries I always get every value I need but the id, which is always 0.

I've no idea how to find my fault - I get a cursor, try to get the id by `long id = cursor.getLong(0)` and it will return 0.

My CreateStatement starts with:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("+ MY_ID_NAME + " LONG PRIMARY KEY, "....
```

Also I need to mention that I work on an In-Memory Database for testing purposes.

What is missing? What am I doing wrong?

Also: I decided to open the database only at the beginning via Singleton-Pattern - this wasn't an issue until now

Edit2: What I also forgot to mention is that I'm currently working in an InstrumentationTestCase-environent for some unit-tests

Comment: have you every commited the insert first?

Comment: As I don't have any parallel tasks at the moment I'm not calling beginTransaction, SetTransactionSuccessful or endTransaction. Do I need this when I call the methods in sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of testing and debugging, Zolnoor's answer was nearly correct:

SQLite does not allow a `LONG PRIMARY KEY` statement but an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` as described in the [SQLite-Documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

> The data for rowid tables is stored as a B-Tree structure containing one entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the key. This means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast. Searching for a record with a specific rowid, or for all records with rowids within a specified range is around twice as fast as a similar search made by specifying any other PRIMARY KEY or indexed value.
>
> With one exception noted below, if a rowid table has a primary key that consists of a  single column and the declared type of that column is "**INTEGER**" in any mixture of upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid. Such a column is usually referred to as an "integer primary key". A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER". Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column with integer affinity and a unique index, not as an alias for the rowid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive that the primary ID number in Android's SQLite must be called `_id` during table creation and referred to when querying the table as `_ID`.

so in this case:

`"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(_id LONG PRIMARY KEY, "....`

Edit:

Try this:

`"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("+ MY_ID_NAME + " LONG PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "...`

Although I am curious why you choose to use `LONG` instead of `INTEGER`

Comment: private static final String MY_ID_NAME = "_id"; - sorry I forgot to mention this ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks but this doesn't work either... The database is returning a valid id, but when I try to use this id it simply returns 0. It's like there is a magic column for the id and my primary key is ignored.  Btw: I use long because of the inconsistency of SQLite in Android (e.g. db.replace returns long) - any other idea? :(

Comment: If I call SELECT * from TABLE_NAME I get exatly the amount of items I'd expect - with all of the values but not the id :( this is unbelivable...

Comment: Okay the only things I can think of: I don't know what your `myValues` contains, but instead of null in `db.update(...)` try listing one of the columns you're updating. Null works unless your `myValues` is empty. I honestly can't think of anything else except maybe making your primary `_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT`